# Decode mail encoded-words =?utf-8?B?xxxx?=, =?utf-8?Q?xxxx?=

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to decode email subjects that are encoded? I know the dirty way of doing it is to get the string character between =?utf-8?B? xxx ?= and decoding that. But I have a program where I can get encoded strings like

```
=?utf-8?Bxxxx?= =?UTF-8?B?xxxx?= ...
```

Right now I'm doing something like this

```
If codedString.ToUpper().StartsWith("=?UTF-8?B?") Then
    Dim temp As String = codedString.SubString(10)
    Dim data = Convert.FromBase64String(temp)
    Dim decodedString = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data)
    'do something with decodedString
End If
```

But this doesn't work when the same string has multiple =?utf-8?B? encode like above. Also I can get strings with =?utf-8?Q encoding and =?windows-1252. Is there a way to tackle all of these encoding? I'm using Visual Studios 2017

Comment: You can study [RFC 1342](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1342) and figure it out, or you can look to see if someone else has written an article with a title like [Parsing and Decoding Values of Some Email Message Fields](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1198601/Parsing-and-Decoding-Values-of-Some-Email-Message).

Answer (score 0):

I've never had trouble using this function to decode a email field value:

It finds matching utf-8 strings for types B or Q, and if type B, runs FromBase64String.
I'm sure you can manipulate for windows-1252.

```
Private Function DecodeEmailField(byVal strString as String) as String
    DecodeEmailField = strString.toString()
    Dim strMatch

    Dim arrEncodeTypes = New String() {"B","Q"}
    Dim strEncodeType as String
    For Each strEncodeType in arrEncodeTypes    

        Dim objRegexB as RegEx = new RegEx("(?:\=\?utf\-8\?" & strEncodeType & "\?)(?:.+?)(?:\?=\s)", _
            RegexOptions.Multiline or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)          

        if (objRegexB.IsMatch(DecodeEmailField)) then
            Dim thisMatch as Match = objRegexB.Match(DecodeEmailField)      
            For Each strMatch in thisMatch.Groups
                Dim strMatchHold as String = strMatch.toString().Substring(("=?utf-8?" & strEncodeType & "?").length)   
                strMatchHold = strMatchHold.SubString(0,(strMatchHold.Length)-("?= ".Length))

                If strEncodeType = "B" Then
                    Dim data() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(strMatchHold)
                    strMatchHold = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)    
                End If                                          

                DecodeEmailField = Replace(DecodeEmailField,strMatch.toString(),strMatchHold)

            Next
        End If  
    Next        

End Function
```